# How to add '|' Pipe in each cell at end of the word in my excel sheet using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python, I was trying to convert my excel data into `.txt` format by pipe (|) delimited.

I have around 250 rows in my excel, i was trying to get an output in the .txt file like below

```
State|County|Zip|Address
Newyork|Albany|10054|59th st,cass ave,apt9|
illinois|lisle|60072|brook ave,steve blvd|
```

Comment: use to_csv, with different separator

Comment: You have to specify `sep="|"` when you call `.to_csv()`.

Comment: But it isn't a csv; it's an excel. Could use something like https://www.penwatch.net/cms/excel_to_csv/

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 "convert my excel data in to .txt format by pipe (|) delimited." They want `to_csv`.

Comment: Thanks DyZ,FHTMitchell ,Here is my code and it is working fine

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 # Read the file
data = pd.read_excel(r'Excle file location')
dataincsv = data.to_csv(r'to csv location',sep=r'|')

Answer (score 3):

Just to sum up, you want `dataframe.to_csv(file, sep='|')`.

See the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

---

If you need help reading the excel file, well that depends on the format.